# Usage of "be up + some percent"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Our income is up %15.

What does it mean? Our income is just a little over &15? or is it below %15 but very close to %15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Our income is up 15%" is a comparison to your income when it was at some other level.

This other income level can be stated explicitly: "Our income is up 15% *since we started selling product X*"; "Our income is up 15% *over last year*." Or it can be *implied* which two time periods you are comparing: "We were barely scraping by during those war years, but now our income is up 15%."

Example - If the income was **100** before, now it is "up 15%"; in other words, now it is **115**. (The linguistic meaning is "exactly 15%", but of course, in reality, the context & other words will tell you how precise you should understand the 15% to be.)

Comment: Thank you. I still have some question. I would like to ask you if possible: Can I use "by" in that sentence: Our income is up by %15. Would that be an improvement? Do we omit "by" in everyday speech?

Comment: I have *never* seen the percentage symbol put before a number before. Is it appropriate in some context I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Jason Bassford , Oh! I guess I haven't either. It didn't jump out at me as unusual though, so I just repeated it that way. Will fix. You must be right.

Comment: @Talha Özden , as far as I know, "up 15%" and "up **by** 15%" are completely interchangeable. Neither is more formal, more correct, or more idiomatic. But please note Jason Bassford's comment about the placement of the percent sign, after the number - just like in speech, where we say "fifteen percent", not "percent fifteen."

Comment: @LorelC. "Just as in speech" is not a good argument. "£15" = "Fifteen pound".

Comment: You are right about money units being "backwards" to this pattern. I didn't mean my statement as an argument for correctness, just as a description of the way we write percentages (the same way we say them).